# Getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$website = $_POST['valorCaja1'];
$enlace_name = $_POST['valorCaja2'];
$link = $_POST['valorCaja3'];

include("connection.php");

if (!$website || !$enlace_name || !$link) {
echo 'No existen las variables';

}else{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (enlace, enlace_name, website, Created) VALUES (:link, :enlace_name, :website, NOW())";
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql); // Here is the problem :(

    $query->execute(array(
        ':link' => $link,
        ':enlace_name' => $enlace_name,
        ':website' => $website
    ));
    echo $handler->lastInsertId();
    $resultado = 'El Enlace ha sido registrado exitosamente!!';
    echo $resultado;
}
?>
```

I have done everything to fix it but I couldn't.

Comment: Where is `$handler` defined? Your error message suggests it is not the object is should be.

Comment: The strange is that when I put the variables direct in that file, I mean that the file works great, but when I pass variable from one page to another 
happens this!!

Comment: Thanks for notice me about that $handler, It was the wrong variable

Comment: probably in the HTML form itself; can't tell for sure till I see what you've for that. and you are using PDO to connect with and not `mysqli_`, right?

Comment: `Created` also looks suspicious - why is this the only column to start with a capital letter? Double check the name and case.

Comment: @halfer I raised a brow at that too. Exceptions will tell them also.

Answer (score 2):

> *"The strange is that when I put the variables direct in that file, I mean that the file works great, but when I pass variable from one page to another happens this!!"*

Chances are, your form's input elements do not contain "name" attributes, or that they were mispelled, and/or that your form does not specify a POST method.

I.e.:

```
<form method="post" action="your_handler.php">

Website:
<input type="text" name="valorCaja1">

Enlace name:
<input type="text" name="valorCaja2">

Link:
<input type="text" name="valorCaja3">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

Error checking methods: (consult footnotes also)

- Add `$handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so.
- Make sure you are indeed using PDO to connect with, and not `mysqli_`.
- Those different MySQL APIs do **not** intermix with each other.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

**Footnotes:**

Instead of `if (!$website || !$enlace_name || !$link)`, use a conditional `empty()`.

```
if(
    !empty($_POST['valorCaja1']) 
    && 
    !empty($_POST['valorCaja2']) 
    && 
    !empty($_POST['valorCaja3'])
)
{
    $website = $_POST['valorCaja1'];
    $enlace_name = $_POST['valorCaja2'];
    $link = $_POST['valorCaja3'];
...
}
```

> $query = $handler->prepare($sql); // Here is the problem :(

- Make sure your DB contains the same variable to connect with.

I.e.:

```
$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
```

---

**Reference(s):**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php